# Does Google Drive AppFolder (AppData) require it's own explicit scope?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have some code that was able to read and write to the [Drive appfolder (AKA appdata)](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata) that recently stopped working.

It seems the problem is due to consolidation of scopes we were asking for.  Before we requested explicit scopes:

```
www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

But we consolidated them into the top level scope:

```
www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

We can read and find a file in the appfolder, we cannot write to it.  Had to add the drive.appdata scope back.

Is this intended behavior?  Very confused.

NOTE:  Yes I see the name has been changed from appdata to appfolder by Google, so I also switched to using appfolder name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, appdata requires its own scope.

Comment: Do you know why it is that /auth/drive scope is not inclusive of /auth/drive.appdata?  /auth/drive is advertised as a top level scope that is supposed to be inclusive of all other scopes for drive, isn't it?

Comment: /auth/drive gives access to all of a users files.  /auth/drive.appdata is considered different because it allows you to store hidden application information, which is somewhat distinct fro user files.  Sorry the documentation isn't clear.